# SVG Blend Mode Multiply IE11 & EXCEL 2019

Tags: excel, svg, heatmap

I am trying to create heatmaps using SVG. The idea is that a service pulls the data from a DB, composes the SVG image, and passes it on to the client for rendering.

The whole process works fine in the browser, well most browsers, but it fails where it matters the most which is when the image is loaded in EXCEL (using EXCEL 2019 for an internal application).

My search so far indicates that the component used by EXCEL is based on IE11 does not implement `mix-blend-mode:multiply` in a way the the SVG is currently composed.

The following image shows how the SVG is rendered using IE11 (left image) vs EDGE (right image).
[image: IE11 VS EDGE]

EDGE provides the expected render, while IE11 does not.

As I am trying to utilise the client resources for the rendering I am looking for an option along the lines of:

1. Render the SVG using a command line tool. Note: imagemagick renders the SVG in the same way as IE11
2. Implement `mix-blend-mode:multiply` using an alternative way that is compatible with IE11, however I got to work with the restriction that the image is ultimately going to be embedded into a spreadsheet, therefore I can't use javascript within the SVG (or can I?).

Can anyone provide some pointers on any of the two approaches above?

The actual SVG code used for the images above is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 138 524 524" width="524" height="524">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .class-p-0 {mix-blend-mode:multiply}
        </style>
        <filter id="heatmap-filter">
            <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" />
                <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" />
                <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" />
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.9" intercept="0" />
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
        <radialGradient id="heatmap-fill">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9a9a9a" stop-opacity="0.8" />
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9a9a9a" stop-opacity="0.0" />
        </radialGradient>
        <circle id="p-0" class="class-p-0" fill="url(#heatmap-fill)" cx="0" cy="0" r="32" />
    </defs>
    <g filter="url(#heatmap-filter)">
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(344.792 325.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(34.06 211.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(320.688 255.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(420.248 196.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(169.252 342.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(140.432 410.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(107.944 480.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(384.092 434.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(352.128 377.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(32.488 445.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(434.396 323.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(135.716 428.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(241.04 508.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(34.06 315.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(135.192 268.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(287.152 470.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(279.816 218.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(374.66 422.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(208.552 511.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(106.372 501.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(162.44 426.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(233.18 513.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(139.908 387.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(206.98 544.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(206.456 392.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(18.34 247.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(38.252 236.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(152.484 500.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(145.148 461.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(326.976 360.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(226.892 311.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(292.392 233.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(63.928 320.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(198.596 254.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(255.188 264.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(191.784 332.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(330.12 281.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(85.936 507.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(131.0 360.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(244.708 220.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(67.596 449.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(147.768 479.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(417.628 396.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(398.24 269.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(250.472 574.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(242.612 442.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(189.164 534.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(108.468 310.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(355.272 525.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(96.94 316.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(115.28 352.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(54.496 472.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(221.128 488.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(95.892 564.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(.0 471.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(250.996 355.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(158.772 363.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(198.596 275.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(312.828 216.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(418.676 581.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(257.808 296.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(105.324 465.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(74.932 352.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(235.8 238.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(154.056 520.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(149.864 350.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(182.876 426.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(58.164 340.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(358.94 364.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(175.016 429.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(91.176 314.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(238.42 463.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(322.26 586.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(489.94 349.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(362.084 355.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(374.66 290.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(366.276 471.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(298.68 521.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(485.224 412.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(217.984 467.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(176.064 268.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(46.112 487.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(194.404 420.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(262.524 404.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(69.168 302.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(436.492 262.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(145.148 493.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(336.408 259.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(514.044 241.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(71.788 203.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(289.248 544.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(257.284 564.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(320.688 268.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(178.684 265.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(157.2 498.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(121.568 513.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(244.184 429.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(15.196 240.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(93.796 582.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(114.232 480.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(300.252 429.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(216.412 425.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(345.84 363.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(201.74 363.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(149.864 465.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(366.276 278.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(81.744 523.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(227.416 300.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(153.008 364.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(441.208 505.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(218.508 266.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(381.996 263.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(344.792 356.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(466.36 202.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(474.744 264.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(166.632 506.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(227.416 550.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(46.636 368.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(247.328 433.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(290.296 435.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(34.06 439.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(434.396 211.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(131.0 335.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(363.132 523.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(178.16 548.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(200.168 283.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(345.84 493.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(215.888 379.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(474.744 265.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(352.652 265.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(292.916 451.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(38.776 492.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(321.212 531.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(221.128 446.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(44.54 296.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(143.052 325.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(242.612 384.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(243.136 306.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(425.488 231.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(208.552 517.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(264.096 223.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(179.208 465.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(231.608 364.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(82.268 276.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(253.616 379.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(58.164 428.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(421.82 433.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(157.724 336.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(176.588 344.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(243.136 428.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(250.996 291.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(352.128 332.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(380.424 555.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(248.9 320.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(219.556 422.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(172.92 327.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(35.632 321.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(171.348 425.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(197.024 251.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(262.0 400.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(86.984 385.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(66.024 236.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(160.868 456.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(252.044 219.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(217.984 431.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(148.292 600.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(488.368 432.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(189.164 332.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(158.772 509.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(79.648 340.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(300.252 582.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(381.996 422.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(123.664 430.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(334.836 547.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(321.212 359.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(250.996 317.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(80.172 232.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(56.068 361.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(216.412 369.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(358.416 334.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(104.8 330.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(262.0 262.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(504.088 446.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(142.004 600.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(173.444 342.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(230.036 356.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(435.968 328.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(221.128 262.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(176.588 390.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(333.264 448.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(171.872 596.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(375.708 331.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(179.732 417.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(224.272 220.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(225.32 337.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(354.224 342.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(174.492 283.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(295.012 324.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(73.36 308.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(365.228 295.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(93.796 227.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(53.972 326.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(336.932 399.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(378.852 228.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(314.4 552.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(219.032 387.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(187.068 444.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(106.896 500.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(166.632 493.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(319.116 515.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(132.572 479.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(155.628 453.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(306.016 331.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(103.752 337.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(268.812 435.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(224.272 332.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(157.2 306.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(92.748 415.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(193.356 453.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(434.396 199.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(152.484 350.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(179.732 347.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(188.64 424.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(406.624 205.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(385.664 237.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(134.144 537.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(383.568 360.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(211.172 262.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(45.064 443.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(459.548 568.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(140.432 504.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(408.196 378.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(182.352 568.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(133.62 338.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(127.856 269.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(313.876 315.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(374.136 508.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(381.996 468.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(450.64 283.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(84.364 239.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(100.608 376.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(104.8 296.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(372.564 312.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(239.468 220.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(157.724 321.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(184.448 379.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(339.552 304.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(192.308 328.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(408.196 305.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(172.92 222.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(226.892 594.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(107.944 439.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(133.62 498.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(227.416 216.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(144.624 424.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(136.24 452.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(268.288 229.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(81.22 484.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(132.048 301.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(52.4 433.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(366.276 278.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(198.596 292.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(221.128 538.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(50.828 372.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(405.052 270.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(179.208 398.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(106.372 262.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(100.608 557.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(190.736 497.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(154.58 449.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(242.612 284.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(155.628 372.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(152.484 503.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(122.092 460.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(101.656 536.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(158.772 469.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(225.32 483.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(350.556 330.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(252.568 274.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(104.8 270.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(33.536 552.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(96.416 371.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(62.356 447.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(466.884 360.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(37.204 500.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(369.42 292.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(38.776 308.0)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(360.512 494.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(95.892 445.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(62.356 243.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(26.2 472.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(341.648 338.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(298.68 518.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(42.968 297.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(199.12 442.4)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(309.684 352.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(58.164 407.2)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(63.928 445.6)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(245.756 244.8)"></use>
        <use xlink:href="#p-0" transform="translate(138.86 389.6)"></use>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Regards,
George

Comment: Installing Inkscape should solve the issue with ImageMagick, it will use it automatically as an external delegate. (Although I have no experience with this on Windows, but the most you would need is some config to make Inkscape available in PATH.) Foregoing ImageMagick, you can also use Inkscape directly as a renderer using its CLI.

Comment: Inkscape should work, as ccprog suggests.  There will be other software that supports blend modes. Apache Batik might. Another alternative would be headless Chrome (eg using puppeteer).

Comment: I did try inkscape, imagemagick and batik...Inkscape was the one that produced the outcome that was closest to what I am getting in Chrome, but still not the same (specially when I started adding more objects in the SVG. I will accept to lose this round.